# Need helping passing javascript variable through hidden form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, I have javascript to calculate a dynamic price for an HTML form. The code is as follows:

```
jQuery("input[name='Amount']").change(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)) || !isFinite(this.value)) {
        jQuery(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
    var calc = parseFloat(this.value) * 0.95;
    jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc);
});
```

This, with this form input:

```
<input class="irrelevant typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="Amount"/>
```

The javascript takes that value, calculates the price, and I want it to fill this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" value=""/>
```

I believe my javascript is correct. What do I need to do to the price  to make it work?

EDIT 2: I resolved it! Thanks guys. The issue was just in the location of the javascript!

Comment: You haven't actually explained what the problem with your code is.

Comment: *"can't get it to work"* What exactly doesn't work? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Can you reproduce the problem with a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo? If you can't properly explain your problem, how do you expect us to be able to help you?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I just had the javascript in the wrong location. Thank you for taking the time to look at this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. This code works perfectly at my side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input class="irrelevant typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="Amount" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery("input[name='Amount']").change(function () {

                if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)) || !isFinite(this.value)) {
                    jQuery(this).val('');
                    return false;
                }
                var calc = parseFloat(this.value) * 0.95;
                jQuery(this).parents("form").find("input[name='price']").val(calc);
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code without explanation? :-/ What did you change? What was the OP's problem?